# Storing SQL query output in an Array

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, database

I'm looking for a way to store the results/output of an SQL Query into an Array. I have a for loop which runs a query and each time the query is ran I would like to store the results in an array/arraylist. I tried using a cursor but I cannot store multiple strings in a cursor.

Here is the for loop:

```
for (int i=1;i<code.length;i++) {
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("codes", new String[]{"description"}, ("code = '" + code[i] + "'"), null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String temp = cursor.getString(i);
        result.add(i, temp);
        cursor.close();
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions or examples that could help?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to store the content of the `Cursor` in the array ?

Comment: Assuming that `code` is a list of ids and the table name is named `codes`, you would like to retrieve the list of descriptions for all the codes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `code` is a list of ids and the table name is named `codes`, and that you would like to retrieve the list of descriptions for all the codesTry you should this (using `StringUtils.join` from [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)):

```
String codes = StringUtils.join(code,",");  
Cursor  cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select description from codes where code in (?)",new String[]{codes});
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
    result.add(cursor.getString(1));
}
cursor.close();
```